# Library linking in C++/Qt distribution

Tags: c++, qt, dll, cmake, static-libraries

I am developing a project in C++11, and am not the biggest expert in distrubition, compiling, packaging, etc. I use

- CMake 3.1.0
- Qt 5.4 (community edition)

Moreover, I want the program to work on both OS X and Windows. Therefore, my IDEs include:

- Apple Xcode 7
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

I am having troubles with the Windows build. As of now, I am not able to copy the executables to another computer, since the DLL-files are not included. If I copy all the DLL-files that I receive errors from, it simply says the program was not able to run. I have read a bit about static library linking, but am unsure whether this is what I need.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
set(libsources file1.cpp file2.cpp)
set(exec1sources file3.cpp file4.cpp)
set(exec2sources file5.cpp file6.cpp)

# some qt commands

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ..)
add_library(sharedlib ${libsources])
generate_export_header(sharedlib)
add_executable(exec1 ${exec1sources})
add_executable(exec2 ${exec2sources})

target_link_libraries(sharedlib Qt5::A Qt5::B)
target_link_libraries(exec1 Qt5::A Qt5::B sharedlib)
target_link_libraries(exec2 Qt5::A Qt5::C sharedlib)

install(TARGETS exec1 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
install(TARGETS exec2 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

As you can probably see, I want 2 executables, that each use some functionality from a shared library. And I want them working stand-alone.

I am likely not the first in the world to have this issue, but I was unable to find a similar thread on StackOverflow.

Comment: `I am not able to copy the executables to another computer, since the DLL-files are not included.` - which DLL-files you mean? QT ones? Also, you copy executables from one Windows machine to another Windows machine *of same architecture*, don't you?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I mean the Qt DLL-files. Mainly. There are also some other required (appear to be related to Visual Studio, I think). I copy from a Windows 7 x32 machine to Windows 10 x64. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, using executable compiled on x32 platform to x64 one could be a problem. For make this executable work, you have at least to install 32-bit Qt on x64 machine. If you want just to copy QT files to target machine, you probably need to copy them into directory with executable itself. Windows has no notion about RPATH, so placing DLLs at the same place as on host doesn't make them searchable (until this place is searched on target machine by default).

Comment: Consider using windeployqt/macdeployqt as Felix suggests, or CPack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#the-windows-deployment-tool)? It will automatically copy all dependencies for you application. You can find it in the bin-folder of your Qt-Kit

For Mac, there is a similar tool, called [macdeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html#the-mac-deployment-tool).